# Is possible to use fwrite from `data.table` with gzfile?

Tags: r, compression, data.table

I'm running an R session in an ssh server, and I have limited storage capacity. I was wondering if there is an implementation of `fwrite` that allows compression? Something like:

```
z <- gzfile("file.csv.gz")
fwrite(object, z)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the gzip function in R.utils:

```
library(R.utils)
library(data.table)

#Write gzip file
df <- data.table(var1='Compress me',var2=', please!')
fwrite(df,'filename.csv',sep=',')
gzip('filename.csv',destname='filename.csv.gz')`

# Read gzip file
fread('gzip -dc filename.csv.gz')
          var1      var2
1: Compress me , please!
```

Answer (score 25):

*UPDATE*: As of 2019-10-03 the below change is also released on CRAN (starting with version 1.12.4), so a simple `install.packages("data.table")` should now suffice.

data.table now supports `fwrite()` directly to gzipped csvs. As of Aug 28 2019 this is not released on CRAN, but you can get it by installing from GitHub:

```
# Install development version of data.table
install.packages("data.table", repos="https://Rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table")

# Generate some data
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  state = sample(state.name, size = 1e6, replace = TRUE),
  measure = runif(1e6)
)

# Write to a gzipped file
data.table::fwrite(dt, file = "dt.gz")

# Read back
library(R.utils)
dt2 <- data.table::fread("dt.gz")
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table::fwrite` does not support connections. If you really need to append a data use the `iotools::write.csv.raw` with `gzfile` connection. Otherwise you should use `writeRDS` or `fst::write_fst` instead.